# Problems with missing information in Obligations when defining using Program in Coq

Tags: coq

I am new to Coq and trying to figure out how to use `Program` to more easily define things and then solve obligations, however, sometimes I am left with obligations that cannot be solved because some information have been lost.

If for example I define the following (a bit contrived but the simplest example I could think of), then the function f if a function that takes two identical even numbers and return the double of that number.

```
Program Definition f {n : nat} (k1 k2 : {j : nat | j + j = n}) : {j : nat | j = n} := k1 + k2.
Next Obligation.
```

The problem is that, when I start solving the first obligation, this is what I am left with

```
  k1, k2 : nat
  ============================
  k1 + k2 = k2 + k2
```

witch can clearly not be solved, as I have lost the information about `k1 + k1 = k2 + k2`, and I am left proving that two arbitrary natural numbers are equal.

Why does this happen, and what do you do in that situation to make Coq remember *"all the assumptions"*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This the work of the `program_simpl` tactic, which is the default `Obligation Tactic` applied whenever you open an `Obligation` (and also to completely solve obligations before you open them). You can turn it off by setting it to `idtac`. If that's too drastic, you can just throw away its results if it fails to solve the obligation outright (so obligations that can be solved automatically are).

```
Require Import Psatz.

#[local] Obligation Tactic := try now program_simpl.
#[program] Definition f {n : nat} (k1 k2 : {j : nat | j + j = n}) : {j : nat | j = n} := k1 + k2.
Next Obligation.
  intros n [k1 ?] [k2 ?]. (* program_simpl is responsible for the usual automatic intros, but now we have to do it *)
  simpl.
  lia.
Qed.
```